# Python - TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'type' and 'int'

Tags: python, class, typeerror, class-variables

I've created a class called Greenfly. Within this class, the get_generations function is supposed to accept an integer value. Later on in my code when I try to use the `self.generations` variable in the function `runmodel()`, I get the error below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User/Documents/SCHOOL/C SCIENCE/Population model/Proper iteration.py", line 123, in <module>
    juvenile.runmodel()
  File "C:/Users/User/Documents/SCHOOL/C SCIENCE/Population model/Proper iteration.py", line 46, in runmodel
    for n in range(1,g + 1):
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'type' and 'int'

class Greenfly:
    def get_generations(self):
        self.generations = int(input("Enter no. of generations:"))
        while self.generations < 5 or self.generations > 25:
            try:
                self.generations = int(input("Please enter a whole number greater than 5 and less than 25.\n"))
                if self.generations > 5 or self.generations < 25:
                    pass
                else:
                    self.generations = int(input("Please enter a number greater than 5 and less than 25.\n"))
            except ValueError:
                print("This is not accepted.")
                break

def runmodel(self):
    # i == because the first generation is generation 0#
    i = 0
    g = self.generations
    alteredpopulation = self.population * self.survival_rate
    for n in range(1,g + 1):
        i += 1
        if i == self.generations:
            print("Generation Zero Population:", self.population)
            for n in range(i):
                print(alteredpopulation)
                alteredpopulation *= self.survival_rate
```

This is all of my code if you want to see how it fits in the main program. I don't know if I'm using classes properly but I don't want to use global variables as that's not 'pythonic.'

```
import sys

class Greenfly:

    population = float
    survival_rate = float
    birth_rate = float
    generations = int

    def getattributes(self):
        self.population = float(input("Enter population numbers:"))
        self.survival_rate = float(input("Enter survival rate:"))

    def get_birthrate(self):
        self.birth_rate = float(input("Enter birth rate:"))

    def get_generations(self):
        self.generations = int(input("Enter no. of generations:"))
        while self.generations < 5 or self.generations > 25:
            try:
                self.generations = int(input("Please enter a whole number greater than 5 and less than 25.\n"))
                if self.generations > 5 or self.generations < 25:
                    pass
                else:
                    self.generations = int(input("Please enter a number greater than 5 and less than 25.\n"))
            except ValueError:
                print("This is not accepted.")
                break

    def displayattributes(self):
        print("Population:", int(self.population))
        print("Survival rate:", float(self.survival_rate))

    def displayothers(self):
        print("Birthrate:", float(self.birth_rate))
        print("No. of generations:", int(self.generations))

    def runmodel(self):
        # i == because the first generation is generation 0#
        i = 0
        g = self.generations
        alteredpopulation = self.population * self.survival_rate
        for n in range(1,g + 1):
            i += 1
            if i == self.generations:
                print("Generation Zero Population:", self.population)
                for n in range(i):
                    print(alteredpopulation)
                    alteredpopulation *= self.survival_rate

class Mainframe(Greenfly):

    def settings(self):
        self.defaultSettings = int(input("\n[1] Set Generation 0 values."
                                         "\n[2] Display Generation 0 values."
                                         "\n[3] Disease factor."
                                         "\n[4] Run model."
                                         "\n[5] Export data."
                                         "\n[6] Exit.\n"))

    def resetmenu(self):
        returnbutton = input("Press any key to return to the menu.")
        Mainframe.settings(self)

    def diseasefactor(self):
        print("The disease factor works.")
        Mainframe.resetmenu(self)

    def exportdata(self):
        print("Check excel for popualtion data.")
        Mainframe.resetmenu(self)

print("AQA Population Model")
x = Mainframe()
x.settings()
juvenile = Greenfly()
adult = Greenfly()
senile = Greenfly()

while True:
    try:
        if x.defaultSettings == 1:
            print("Set Generation Zero values.\n")
            print("Juvenile:")
            juvenile.getattributes()
            print("\n")

            print("Adult:")
            adult.getattributes()
            print("\n")

            print("Senile:")
            senile.getattributes()
            print("\n")

            print("Birth rate:")
            x.get_birthrate()
            print("No. of generations:")
            x.get_generations()
            x.resetmenu()
        elif x.defaultSettings == 2:
            print("Generation Zero values are as follows:")
            print("Juvenile:")
            juvenile.displayattributes()
            print("Adult:")
            adult.displayattributes()
            print("Senile:")
            senile.displayattributes()
            x.displayothers()
            x.resetmenu()

        elif x.defaultSettings == 3:
            x.diseasefactor()
            x.resetmenu()
        elif x.defaultSettings == 4:
            juvenile.runmodel()
            adult.runmodel()
            senile.runmodel()
            x.resetmenu()
        elif x.defaultSettings == 5:
            x.exportdata()
            x.resetmenu()
        elif x.defaultSettings == 6:
            sys.exit("Thank you for using the AQA population model")
        else:
            print("Unable to compute your request.")
            x.resetmenu()
    except ValueError:
        print("Not allowed.")
        # This does not work if the first input is a float or string. Only works for integers. #
```

Comment: You don’t declare variables in Python; `generations = int` assigns the `int` type to `Greenfly.generations`.

Answer (score 0):

in short, you have to make sure self.generation is an integer, that is what the error means

```
   def run_model()
       g = self.generation # make sure it is an integer
```

You could do in a few ways:

```
    @property
    def generation(self):
        return self.get_generation()

    def get_generation(self):
        #keep current code of input
        # define generation variable here
        return generation # add a return here
```